# Why am I getting an apache server error page on a django vhost using underscore in my subdomain?

Tags: django, apache, vhosts, django-1.5

I'm using django 1.5.0 and apache 2.2.22. I can't seem to get my site running as a named vhost (I've got other django sites already running fine on this server).

I'm getting the standard apache 500 error page. My error log suggests that've I've got a problem with my ALLOWED_HOSTS setting -

```
[Tue Jun 04 10:25:22 2013] [error] [client 31.52.39.247] SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): sub_domain.mydomain.com
```

But my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting looks ok to me -

```
python manage.py shell
>> from django.conf import settings
>> settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS
['sub_domain.mydomain.com', 'livedomain.com']
```

Also - I don't know why I'm getting the apache 500 page rather than the django debug page -

```
>> settings.DEBUG
True
```

Looking at the full stack trace in the error log, I can see that the wsgi app is running - it's definitely running django code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS` should be ignored altogether when you are in `DEBUG=True` so that's strange. I was having an issue similar to this with NGinx where I had an underscore in my host name which meant Django didn't validate it. This might be an issue particularly if you are having Apache rewriting your host header (this was the case for me as nginx was reverse proxying)

Comment: That's interesting - I've got an underscore in my subdomain name. I'll have to change my dns to check it out..

Comment: You can see the regex that validates hosts here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L27 I'm going to add this as an answer as if it doesn't fix your problem it will still help others in the future most likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `ALLOWED_HOSTS` should be ignored altogether when you have `DEBUG=True` so that's strange that you are getting validation errors.

I was having an issue similar to this with nginx where I had an underscore in my host name which meant Django didn't validate it. This might be an issue particularly if you are having Apache rewriting your host header (this was the case for me as nginx was reverse proxying) or your subdomain includes an `_`.

[You can see how Django validates hostnames in the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L27), furthermore, [I wrote a quick blog post on this](http://timmyomahony.com/blog/2013/04/24/suspiciousoperation-invalid-http_host-header-django/) also which might help

Comment: yup, that was it - Thanks Timmy!